# Сканирование qr-кода с автоматическим открытием сайта. Можно ли?

Tags: веб-программирование

Задача такая. При сканировании qr-кода (внутри ссылка сайта), телефон сразу должен переходить по ссылке внутри него. Есть ли возможность так сделать, или всё зависит от приложения, которым сканируешь. Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Действительно зависит от реализации в конкретном приложении, дело в том, что QR код только хранит информацию, но вот как ей распоряжаться, уже дело приложения. Так что создать сам QR с автоматическим переходом не удастся.